# The absence/presence of the modules from core functionality of tensorflow

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

The project I am working on uses some core functionality of the `Tensorflow` library, namely
`tensorflow.python` module.

When running It in the `virtualenv` I can import it without a problem :

```
import tensorflow.python as tf_python
```

However, the same procedure for the docker image with the same version of `Tensorflow` - https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/2.0.0-gpu-py3-jupyter/images/sha256-613cdca993785f7c41c744942871fc5358bc0110f6f5cb5b00a4b459356d55e4?context=explore says that there is no such attribute of module:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

What may be the cause of this issue, and how can one resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide your Dockerfile? Also, have you tried installing TensorFlow and your other requirements on a python image instead of the TensorFlow image you linked? That may fix your issue.

Here is an example Dockerfile for a python project:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

and list your required modules in the requirements.txt file.

Comment: I've simply pulled the image from the `Dockerhub`, so i do not have my own Dockerfile. Naively, it contains all the required packages I need. The issue looks like be caused tohe fact that it is some core backend functionality, not present in the open part of the package. I cannot access this module from `GoogleColab` as well, having installed the same version. The usual modules, described on the `Tensorflow` package, can be imported normally

Comment: I'm not sure how you're structuring your project, or how you are attempting to use the docker image you are pulling, could you please give more details? For instance, typically you pull a docker image and then layer your application on top of that in order to then create an image of your application and run it as a container.

Comment: in my case I do not need to do anything more. The container runs `jupyter notebook` by default and all required dependencies are put in layers.